# jqgrid blank add dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have been trying to use jqgrids, default CRUD options. Below is my code:

```
$("#roleFlexigrid").jqGrid( {
    //url : 'roleList.htm?t=' + new Date().getTime(),
    //method : 'GET',
    datatype : 'jsonstring',
    datastr: gridData,
    colNames : [ 'Name' ],
    colModel : [ {
        name : 'name',
        search : 'true',
        index : 'name',
        width : 665,
        jsonmap : "cell.name"
    } ],
    jsonReader : {
        repeatitems : false,
        root : "rows",
        cell : "cell",
        id : "id",
        page : "page",
        records : "records"
    },
    viewrecords : "true",
    prmNames : {
        rows : "rp",
        sort : "sortname",
        order : "sortorder"
    },
    pager : "#pager",
    rowNum : 10,
    rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
    sortorder : "asc",
    sortname : "name",
    caption : "Roles",
    height : 210
});

$("#roleFlexigrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
    add:true,
    del : true,
    search : true,
    refresh : true
}, {}, // edit parameters
        { // add parameters
            url : 'addRole.htm'             
        });
```

Right now all i am getting is a blank add dialog box, with no fields. How do I configure it to get all the fields and submit url stuff. Also is there a way to customize these CRUD dialog boxes, like adding/changing message or buttons etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try marking the field as [`editable`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options):

```
colModel : [ {
    name : 'name',
    search : 'true',
    index : 'name',
    width : 665,
    jsonmap : "cell.name",
    editable:true
} ],
```

From the docs:

> **editable**
>
> Defines if the field is editable. This option is used in cell, inline and form modules.

Comment: Also is there a way to customize these CRUD dialog boxes, like adding/changing message/titles or buttons names etc.

Comment: There is a limited amount of customization you can do - have a look at this page: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing . But in general, if you need a custom dialog you might want to consider writing your own instead of using the built-in one. It's not *that* hard and you will have full control over the look-and-feel.

Answer (score 0):

for create customize dialog CRUD in jqgrid, just you make this code in jqgrid script end :

```
.navButtonAdd("#id_row_grid",{
                                caption:"Title",
                                buttonicon:"ui-icon-select", //for icon
                                onClickButton:function(){ //for button click in pager
                                    jQuery("#id_form_popup").dialog({ //dialog form use for popup after click button in pager
                                        autoOpen:false,
                                        height: 340,
                                        width: 630,
                                        modal:true
                                    });
                                   jQuery("#id_form_popup").dialog("open");
                                  }
                                });
```

Don't forget for create form for called in button pager jqgrid. just code only for called dialog form, not for create form.Ok. 
thanks.